# Unable to run simple pyspark program

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create an RDD out of one file which is located on a local system. I am using Eclipse IDE on windows. Below is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("FirstProgram").setMaster("Local")
sc = SparkContext("local")
load_data=sc.textFile("E://words.txt")
load_data.collect()
```

Below is my config:
1) `Spark 2.4.4`
2) `Python 3.7.4`

I tried variations with the file path name but no luck. Below are the contents of the project where the file is stored in the source folder still unable to read it. However, I am able to read that file via the same path i.e `E:/words.txt`. I think there is some problem with the `SparkContext` object.

```
 Directory of E:\workspacewa\FirstSparkProject\Sample

10/12/2019  07:33 PM    <DIR>          .
10/12/2019  07:33 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/12/2019  07:34 PM               119 FileRead.py
10/12/2019  06:21 PM               269 FirstSpark.py
02/02/2019  09:22 PM                82 words.txt
10/12/2019  01:22 PM                 0 __init__.py
```

I reinstalled everything and now facing a new error as below:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x000001924C5434C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\siddh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 860, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\siddh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1216, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Either the file doesn't exist in the path that you're specifying or the path you're giving as input is wrong. Try `sc.textFile("E:\words.txt")` if you're on windows

Comment: Yeah I tried it but doesn't work

Comment: Copy the text file in the `"E:\workspacewa\FirstSparkProject\Sample` directory and just say `sc.textFile("words.txt")`. Try if that works

Comment: same error. is there any different way

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of 'ls' and 'pwd' equivalents of windows? Enter them in the directory where words.txt is

Comment: Post the screenshot of `cd`

Comment: I have edited my question with your needs. Please help me. I am able to read the file in core python but not with pyspark

Comment: Put ‘sc.textFile(“E:\workspacewa\FirstSparkProject\Sample\words.txt")’

Comment: I guess there is no problem with the file path. There is some problem in the environment or while creating spark context object. Could you please help with that?

Comment: I have solved the previous error by reinstalling everything again but, now I am facing a new error. Could you please check the edited post @pissall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up all the `temp` files, reinstalled everything and tried it once again with the below code and it works like a charm.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
load_data=sc.textFile("E://long_sample.txt")
load_data.foreach(print())
```